# Calculate how many times a customer have been in contact with two different departmetns

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I'm using PowerBI and have a table called "cases" with the following columns and rows

[image]

I need to calculatee how many times a customer have been in contact with department B in less than one hour after being in contact with department A. In the dataset above, only customerID 1 and 6  are the correct answers.

Additional info: In the real dataset i have more than 4 million rows for cases

I've tried different DAX meassures without any luck :(